# CSS Animation Overflows It's Parent, Despite Overflow: Hidden

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, overflow

I'm trying to do a "material" animation, where a pseudoelement expands on hover.

Demo:

http://codepen.io/Tiger0915/pen/WbxyJB

On `hover`, a `span:after` scales up to fill it's parent.

But look closely at the corners of the `li` during the transition, you can see that it overflows the `border-radius`.

I have:

```
li {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;

  &:hover span:before {
        @include transform(scale(5));
  }
}
```

But for some reason when it's animating, the `overflow: hidden` doesn't work on the corners of the `li`, which are rounded with `border-radius`.

Why doesn't the `overflow: hidden` work with my `border-radius`, only when the transition is happening?

<sup>**Note: This happens only in Chrome.**</sup>

Comment: That's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Really? Wow okay, do you have a bug report I can reference for some more info??

Comment: Glad to know it's not something I did wrong, haha.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82417 | https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71639

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72619

Answer (score 10):

I edited your code see results [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjqGKz)

it chrome BUG with scale and overflow .

for the container that have the ( overflow:hidden )
add ( in your case its the li )

```
position:relative;
z-index:1;
```

Comment: You are my favorite person.