# Button overflow not working properly?

Tags: css, sass

Apparently I've got a small issue with the `overflow` property. I'm currently working on an abstract UI framework named [`uix`](https://janunld.github.io/uix). The problem itself relates to the wave effect generated whenever a user clicks a button. Have a look at the [Github Pages](https://janunld.github.io/uix) Page and try setting the `border-radius` to a higher amount than `3px`. As you maybe noticed the `overflow` doesn't work as soon as the wave will hit the edges of the button element.

The full source code is available at the [Project Page](https://github.com/JanUnld/uix).

I'm using the following code to create the wave behavior.

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: $button-min-width;
  border-radius: $button-border-radius;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  ...
}

.wave {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 50% 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  ...

  &.wave-in {      
    display: inline-block;
    animation: $wave-animation;
    ...
```

```
uix.element(".btn").each(function(el) {
  el.onmousedown = function(e) {

    uix.element(this).addClass("waving");

    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    // Create child span element for wave effect:
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = "wave";
    Object.assign(span.style, {
      "left": (e.clientX - rect.left - (rect.width / 2)) + "px",
      "top":  (e.clientY - rect.top - (rect.width / 2)) + "px"
    });
    this.appendChild(span);

    // Add button wave animation:
    uix.element(span).addClass("wave-in");

    // Remove span after animation ends:
    setTimeout(function() {
      uix.element(this).removeClass("waving");
      span.remove();
      delete span;
    }, 800);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35251771/2565294

Add `z-index: 1;` to the `.btn`, as the answer suggests, this fixes the issue.

Comment: It did. Thought I already tried it. But accidentally tried it at the `span.wave` element. Whatever. Thank you